# Defining Storyboard segue from UITableViewCell loaded from a XIB

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, segue, xib

I have a `UITableViewController` subclass in a Storyboard which loads it's cells from a `UITableViewCell` defined in a XIB file (this is done so that a custom cell can be re-used across a deep hierarchy of table view controllers).

I need to define the segue from this table view controller to the next table view controller. Normally you would do this by control dragging from the cell of the source to the view controller of the destination. But since there are no prototype cells in the source table view controller, there is no way to connect the segue.

Do I have to resort to implementing `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in my table view controller and triggering a manual segue? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, present the new `UIViewController` from `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Since you don't have a prototype cell, you have nothing to link the segue with. Just `-presentViewController:animated:`.

Comment: I would have thought the better approach would be call performSegue:withIdentifier: from didSelectRowForIndexPath, first having created the segue in the storyboard by control-dragging from the source view controller's icon (the yellow thing at the top of its storyboard scene) to the destination VC. I'd still like an answer to the OP's question though, a way to achieve this without didSelectRowForIndexPath.

Comment: @RobertAtkins `presentViewController:animated:` does the same as `performSegue:withIdentifier:`, one with a storyboard and one without, I can see him going either way. I don't think there is another way to do this without didSelectRowAtIndexPath and I have no clue why you would ever want to avoid it. OP didn't ask to avoid it.